# JSON Definition inside JSON Object inside Schema not Obeying Enums: Python jsonvalidation

Tags: json, validation, python-2.7, jsonschema

I am writing a vcxproj generator for my own personal use. Part of this project is having me learn about JSON schema. Below is the Schema I have defined. (Problem defined after schema).

```
    self._schema = {
        'definitions': {

            ...

            'project_settings': {
                'required': ['configuration', 'platform'],

                'type': 'object',
                'properties': {
                    'platform': {
                        'enum': ['x86_64', 'Win32']
                    },
                    'connfiguration': {
                        'enum': ['Release', 'Debug']
                    },

                    ...    

                }
            }
        },

        # Start of actual requirements
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'project_configurations': {
                'type': 'array',
                'minItems': 1,
                'items': {
                    'allOf': [{'#ref': 'definitions/project_settings'}]
                }
            }
        },
        'additionalProperties': False,
        'required': ['project_configurations'],
    }
```

My issue resides in the `#definitions/project_settings/configuration` and `#definitions/project_settings/platform`. If I provide the following JSON to be validated by python's `jsonschema.validate` it is considered valid, when I think the enums should be failing.

```
{
  "project_configurations": [
    {
      "configuration": "taoshwu",
      "platform": "esostat"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The $ref keyword is not correct.

Try:

```
'$ref':'#/definitions/project_settings'
```